# What is recommended way to create and analyze dump from ASP.NET Core 8 application running in docker container?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, azure-aks, .net-8.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 8 application, containerized (using MSBuild, without dockerfile) running in AKS. It is stable (not crashing, not leaking) but the memory usage is higher than expected.

I've managed to connect to pod shell

```
kubectl exec -n prod --stdin --tty my-api-77cff99b66 -- /bin/bash
```

but since the base image is ASP.NET Core runtime only, tools like `dotnet-counters` and `dotnet-dump` are not present, and cannot be installed. User is not root (`whoami` is giving `app`), there is no `sudo`, therefore no `apt install`.

What is recommended way to create and analyze dump from production application running on runtime (not SDK) image? Is it even possible? Or do I need to rebuild image with SDK base image and/or root user, and deploy it to production?

Comment: @Arko this is ChatGPT generated comment, isn't t?

Comment: I guess any ai or google would recommend the same rouen. That's the only two options I can see. Even as per MS Doc- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/diagnostics-in-containers